# How can I change paper size in Windows 10 native scanning agent?

Tags: windows-10, scanning

My Windows 10 always requests my scanner to scan in Legal instead of A4:

[image]

And it won't let me change it (field is disabled).

Is there any way I can override that / set the default / force my Windows 10 to scan in A4 by default and always?

Comment: Try using the HP scanning app, if it is not there download and install the printer driver from HP

Comment: That suggestion is opposite the way how am I using Windows (and devices in general). If something can be achieved in native system solution then I see no point in installing a separate app. Aside above, native Windows 10's scan driver and software does its job so installing huge 150+ MB pack from HP isn't an option for me. Plus that it does not work at all in certain scenarios -- i.e. fails to find my network printer and scanner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to [messy design in Windows' native scan driver and software](https://onezeronull.com/2021/03/15/change-page-size-when-scanning-in-windows-10/#power8230-that-is-not-in-your-hands) you cannot change this.

When doing each scan you have to:

- Change scan mode to document feeder for a moment
- Set page size (only then corresponding list will be enabled) and
- Change scan mode back to flatbed

This must be done each time, because there's seems to be no permanent solution for this.